# How to apply AcousticEchoCanceler onSIPDemo on android?

Tags: android

[I encountered same problem with him] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768599/how-to-get-audiosessionid-from-sip-call-on-android)

I used sample Android code(SipDemo) to implement simple SIP client, but noticed strong echo while calling.

I found new(API 16) Android class AcousticEchoCanceler that can reduce echo effect but i don't know where can i get AudioSessionId.

AcousticEchoCanceler aec = AcousticEchoCanceler.create(int audioSession);
Can anyone help me with this? How to get AudioSessionId from Sip call?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a `AudioRecord` object initialized somewhere to record from the mic. Use the `getAudioSessionId()` method on that object to get the session ID.